# scala external command with parameter

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and this question is simple parameter passing to another command.

```
val p = "/usr/tmp"

val status = Seq("/bin/sh", "-c", "rm -f $p/*.txt").!
```

the $p value seems to be not passing correctly, can some one please help me understand on how to pass val p as a param to next val command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string needs to start with 's' to use string interpolation

```
val status = Seq("/bin/sh", "-c", s"rm -f $p/*.txt").!
```